# Dreaded compound quoting in macros

Tags: string, stata, double-quotes

I think of myself as an advanced Stata user, but I just cannot figure out how to make the compound quotes work for me.

I have two macros, each containing compound quoted lists like `"name with space"' `"nospace"'. I can't figure out how to treat those chunks of string as space-separated lists.

If I create a local with no quotes, it looks like a list separated by a space. E.g.,

```
 local test a b

. di "`test'"
a b
```

But if I put them in compound quotes, I get something very different:

```
. local test `"a"' `"b"'

. di "`test'"
a' invalid name
r(198);

. di `"`test"'
ab
```

This is a problem if I want to have chunks of strings treated as individual items, as below:

```
local set1 `"name with space"' `"nospace"'

. di `"`set1'"'
name with spacenospace
```

How can I make the macro be a list of string chunks (with or without spaces), separated by spaces? I'd ultimately like to iteratively build up such a macro and use it to name rows in a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this answers all your questions. Perhaps edit the questions and remove everything about matrices. As far as I understand your question is about strings and matrices just happens to be the context of your question. But I might be wrong. If your question is about strings only, then a reproducible example focusing on strings would improve your chances on getting a complete answer.

In `` local set1 `"name with space"' `"nospace"' `` you concatenate two strings `"name with space"` and `"nospace"` but you do not tell Stata to add a space in between those strings. Stata will not add anything in between those strings without you telling it to do so.

You could, for example, do:

```
local set1 `"name with space"' `" "' `"nospace"'
di `"`set1'"'
```

or:

```
local set1 `"name with space"' `" nospace"'
di `"`set1'"'
```

or save a string of strings:

```
local set1 `" "name with space" "nospace" "'
di `"`set1'"'
```

Comment: Neither of those solve the issue though. One adds an element to the set1 macro, a space, which gets concatenated on display, and the other arbitrarily changes one of the strings, but they still get concatenated together.

Comment: But I agree editing to focus on the string issue will help.

Comment: I have added a third example, does that help?

Comment: that does help! can you explain why it works?

Comment: Enclosing a string in `\`"` and `"'`  tells Stata to treat a `"` in the string as a character and not as the end of the string unless it is immediately followed by `'` as in `"'`

Comment: A golden rule is that each time Stata processes a string with outermost double quotes or compound double quotes, those outermost double quotes are removed as delimiters. So, what is left has to make sense in turn.

Comment: Thanks Nick - I think that might have been the source of my misunderstanding.